# Drupal Feeds Excel Error

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-feeds

I'm getting this error when using the feeds excel module:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getConfig() on a non-object in modules/feeds_excel/feeds_excel.module on line 56

```
function feeds_excel_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'feeds_ui_mapping_form') {
    $config = $form['#importer']->getConfig(); //line 56
    if ($config['parser']['plugin_key'] == 'ExcelParser') {
```

Any suggestions?